# IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface despite @NoRepositoryBean

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

**Context**

I'm upgrading a spring 4 application to spring 5. In the process I had to upgrade spring-jpa from 1.6.5.RELEASE to 2.1.5.RELEASE.

**Problem**

At startup, I get an error indicating that no suitable constructor is found on an interface. That repository interface however is annotated with @NoRepositoryBean and shouldn't be implemented since it is extended by other interfaces.

How can I make sure this interface is not picked up by data-jpa? Why did it start after dependency upgrades?

**Interface code**

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
        extends JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
    // method declarations but no constructor
}
```

**Stacktrace**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface org.organisation.ExtendedJpaRepository to match the given arguments: [class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation, class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156]. Make sure you implement a constructor taking these
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.lambda$getTargetRepositoryViaReflection$4(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:514)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:514)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepositoryViaReflection(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:123)
```

Comment: The annotation is useless as it doesn't do anything on an interface it belongs on an implementation. The interface is detected due to it extending `JpaRepository` which is the trigger for Spring Data JPA to instantiate it.

Comment: How can I prevent this error then? Why did it start happening after an upgrade?

Comment: It isn't just an upgrade you are upgrading and skipping a couple of versions. I suggest you read the release notes / upgrade guide of those releases to see what changed. What is this `ExtendedJpaRepository`? Do you also have a custom implementation for it? If so your interface should probably not extend `JpaRepository`. (Although you probably in your other interfaces only want to extend this `ExtendedJpaRepository` interface?